# i need help converting my jquery 1.3 code to jquery 2.2.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.3

So i have a chatroom site built with php and jquery but it is using 2 different versions of jquery and some of the new pages i have added conflict with each other 
(even though i had both jquery versions linked at the same time on the other pages) so i need help converting the code over for i do not know what is depreciated and what is not here is my jquery 1.3 code

```
    // jQuery Document
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //If user submits the form
        $("#submitmsg").click(function() {
            var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
            $.post("/chatPost/defaultchatpost.php", {
                text: clientmsg
            });
            $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
            return false;
        });
        //Load the file containing the chat log
        function loadLog() {
            var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/chatLogs/defaultchatlog.html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox  div
                    var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
                    if (newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight) {
                        $("#chatbox").animate({
                            scrollTop: newscrollHeight
                        }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                    }
                },
            });
        }
        setInterval(loadLog, 500); //Reload file every 2.5 seconds
        //If user wants to end session
        $("#exit").click(function() {
            var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
            if (exit == true) {
                window.location = 'defaultchat.php?logout=true';
            }
        });
    });
```

can someone please help me it would be greatly appreciated i have tried to figure this out for a long time

Comment: There's nothing needs doing to that jQuery as far as I can see, are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: I dont know its just not doing anything with jquery 2.2.2

Comment: Check the docs you don't have that many functions here.

Comment: If you hit f12 do you get any errors in console?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function` but that code is for something else on another page linked to this

Comment: You don't have `.live` in your code! The code by itself works ok. the problem is elsewhere. Do a text search for `.live`

Comment: looks like that code stops javascript from running on your page. You should inspect that file that this error is coming from and preferably fix it, since $(el).live() is depreciated from 1.7

Comment: use the jquery migrate plugin.

Comment: i have switched back and forth between jquery 1.3 and 2.2.2 to see if it will work with 2.2.2 but it only works with 1.3

Answer (score 0):

It seems your trying to call /chatLogs/defaultchatlog.html from your main interface using ajax html. In that case you do not have to add jquery in your defaultchatlog.html, even in other ajax called html files. All functions must be in the main UI not in the partial html files which are called via ajax html. For example: main.html and defaultchatlog.html... I hope this helps

main.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <scrpt src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chatWindows"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url: "chatlog.html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#chatWindows").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox  div
            },
        });
        });
        function clearLogs(){
            $("#logs").empty();
        }
    </script>
</html>

chatlog.html

<div>
    <ul id="logs">
        <li>Hi</li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="clearLogs();">Clear</button>
</div>
```